# Adding 3 Logos at the top of the screen

Tags: html, alignment

I'm new to HTML and trying to work on a practice project.
What I'm stuck with is adding 3 logos at the top of the page 1 in the left 1 in the middle and 1 in the right.
I tried to follow previous methods like using floats and flex method but I either end up with all the images side by side and can't move their positions or just one under an other !
How can I do that?

Comment: Please add your HTML structure. It's hard to debug without proper requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, welcome in the wonderful world of HTML !

**Here's the HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
 <img class="logo" src="yourlogo.png"/>
 <img class="logo" src="yourlogo.png"/>
 <img class="logo" src="yourlogo.png"/>
</div>
```

---

**And the CSS...**

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center
}
```

I can give you some ressources for learn Flexbox! Flex are wonderful and you can do a lot of cool things very easily

[Flexbox introduction on CSS TRICKS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Flexbox froggy (little game for understanding flex's logic)](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you for the resources ! And yes it worked ! I just need to edit the size of the images now so they are positioned correctly, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You could use **flex** and **justify-content** to achieve this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between">

<img src="https://picsum.photos/100/50" />

<img src="https://picsum.photos/100/50" />

<img src="https://picsum.photos/100/50" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```